# Error "Could not resolve all files for configuration" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I try to run an app that have no visible error in coding. However when I try to run it this error pop up:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Not sure this error is important or not but I'll show here anyway:

```
API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see TBD.
To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
```

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please spell-check your post, refrain from adding any begging material, and use the formatting tools provided. This will help your post obtain the best reception.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried turning off The offline mode ?
On the top right side of the Window .

Click on Gradle 2nd number option(just near of Setting option) click on it then you will be able to do work continue sally.

As you can see the image
[image: AndroidStudioScreensot]

Comment: I tried this it still doesn't work sadly. Ive been googling the solution for a very long time No cached version of com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project   ***it gimme this extra error when i turn it off

Comment: No cached version of com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project