# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have next problem with my android studio

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

I allready tried this solutions but not working.

[Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)

[Error "Could not resolve all files for configuration" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095576/error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-in-android-studio/71095604)

problem ocours when i add dependency from thirdpart library to gradle.

Comment: Can please post the entire error log(if any)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your settings.gradle file has the maven url `maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}`

Should look like this :

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
}
```

Comment: I don't know why settings.gradle should have  that repositories. settings.gradle  or build.gradle?

Comment: settings.gradle at older version of Android Studio, but build.gradle (project level) at Android studio Bumblebee or later.