# $ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, mvvm, build.gradle

I am trying to make a Spotify clone app in Kotlin. I have not completed it yet but while checking whether it is running or not, i encountered with this error:-

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

My App keeps crashing when i run it on the emulator

I have tried the following solutions:-

1. [Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370973/could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugruntimeclasspath-prob)
2. [Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)
3. [Error "Could not resolve all files for configuration" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095576/error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-in-android-studio/71095604)

Build.gradle(module: app):-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aashushaikh.spotifyclone"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'

    // Activity KTX for viewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")


    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // Firebase Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.2.0'

    // Firebase Storage KTX
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:24.2.0'

    // Firebase Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'

    // ExoPlayer
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.0"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.0"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.18.0"
}
```

Build.gradle(project level):-

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Settings.gradle(Project settings):-

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "SpotifyClone"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should this version: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'`

You can find current versions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#kotlin+ktx